# InfoPathform not submitting to sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: list, infopath

I've set up an InfoPath form and SP list. It was working fine and submitting to the list. However I set up some Form Load and Form Submit rules which threw up some errors. Then I noticed that the data wasn't appearing in the list. When I submit the form nothing happens. No errors, the form just closes and nothing appears in the list. I've disabled the rules, so theoretically I should be back to where I was, but I'm actually a step back. Any ideas why the data isn't appearing on the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verify that there is no "Close form" action in your previous rules. Also Make sure that you moved your form actions up i.e. before your submit action. otherwise values which you will try to set from your rules will not get submitted.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you set up custom actions for form submit?

[image]

If you did this, be sure to set up custom submit rule

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to this type of problem is to really step back, disable all rules and keep simple form submit to list. Test that and if that works then apply rules one by one and test until you come to a rule that cause the issue.